# Why there is no semantic check for ddl statement inside if exists in mssql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why this (ddl) works with no compilation error?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[TableDoesNotExits]') = object_id) 
BEGIN 
    ALTER TABLE  [dbo].[TableDoesNotExits] ADD RandomColumn INT --Works fine
END
```

While this (dml) does not? *Gives compilation error as mentioned in the query comment*
Works when wrapped inside a dynamic query? (using sp_executesql)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='TableExists' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnDoesNotExists')
BEGIN
    UPDATE 
        dbo.TableExists
    SET 
        ColumnDoesNotExists = 1 --Invalid column name 'ColumnDoesNotExists'
    WHERE 
        1 = 1
END
```

Comment: why are you comparing apples and oranges?

Comment: I'm comparing ddl and dml? I do not understand apple and oranges analogy? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: you do know the difference between DDL and DML right?

Comment: Yes,I do. One is definition and other is for manipulation. I'm talking about the sql parsing. Why one parses while other don't. I wanted to know the exact reason for it.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I hope you learnt something new today than the difference between ddl and dml. Please look at the answer provided.

Comment: Zammy, you should take note of what @maSTAShuFu says: DDL statements are intended to alter schema, the rules can be expected to be different to DML statements which operate on existing schema. Modify your DDL query to operate on an _existing_ table and it _still won't_ perform semantic 'compile-time' checks. E.g. `alter table TableExists add AlreadyExists int` or `alter table TableExists alter column DoesNotExist int`. So the answer you've accepted may be informative, but is not strictly speaking correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example you are referencing a non-existing table.

In your second example you reference a non-existent column in an existing table.

Those two cases are different in how SQL Server performs compilation.

You can read more about that in this link about "Deferred Name Resolution":

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx

I quote here the most relevant paragraph:

> Deferred name resolution can only be used when you reference nonexistent table objects. All other objects must exist at the time the stored procedure is created. For example, when you reference an existing table in a stored procedure you cannot list nonexistent columns for that table.

Comment: While yes, deferred name resolution could be a factor, that's not really what's at play in OP's question. As @maSTAShuFu pointed out, comparing DDL and DML is like comparing apples and oranges. DDL statements are intended to alter schema, the rules can be expected to be different to DML statements which operate on existing schema. Modify OP's DDL query to operate on an _existing_ table and it _still won't_ perform semantic 'compile-time' checks. E.g. `alter table TableExists add AlreadyExists int` or `alter table TableExists alter column DoesNotExist int`